# An open source program or spreadsheet to use for solving cutting stock problems / making cut lists?

Tags: open-source

I'm looking for an open source software or spreadsheet that can calculate cut lists (solve the [cutting list problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem)). I'm looking for a similar function as these web apps:

- https://www.cutlistoptimizer.com/
- https://www.kurraglenindustries.com.au/linear-cutting-list-calculator.htm